# C free char* allocated on heap

Tags: c, memory-leaks, char, heap-memory, free

Is there a memory leak in the following code example as I have allocated memory on the heap for name which hasn't been freed? If I add free(person->name); before the free(person); line then I get a runtime error in VS "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer".

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER

typedef struct person {
 char *name;
} Person;

#endif
```

source.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

#define BUFFERSIZE 500

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
 Person *person = NULL;
 char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
 printf("Enter name\n");
 fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
 {
  char *name; 
  person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
  name = malloc(strlen(buffer));
  strcpy (name,buffer);
  person->name = name;
 }
 free(person); 
 return 0;
}
```

Thanks, Rob

Comment: 2 allocs vs 1 free. What do you expect?

Comment: Compare:  mkdir person; mkdir person\name; deltree /Y person.  Two resource allocations, one resource release.  free doesn't work that way, and now he knows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the code has a memory leak.

The culprit is:
`name = malloc(strlen(buffer));` which should be
`name = malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);` to account for `\0`.

You should now be able to free `person->name`.

Answer (score 10):

strlen doesn't account for the null-terminator that strcpy adds, you'll need to "malloc(strlen(buffer)+1)"

Comment: You can call strdup, for a one pass, malloc+1 and copy on a string operation.

Comment: `strdup()` is, however, nonstandard C. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is a memory leak.

You allocate a name buffer:

```
name = malloc(strlen(buffer));
```

and never deallocate it. Then when you deallocate the `Person`,

```
free(person);
```

you lose your last pointer to that buffer, so you can *never* deallocate it.

The error message you are getting is a separate issue related to the length of the name buffer that you allocate being insufficient to include the null termination of the string you try to copy into it.

Answer (score 1):

`name` is never freed, so it leaks.

Complex heap-allocated structures like this are often best handled by a move to C++, or (if that isn't feasible) by wrapping the memory management in custom create/destroy/manipulation functions:

```
Person *CreatePerson(void) {
    /* you can use calloc() here, of course */
    Person *result = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    if (result) {
        memset(result, 0, sizeof(Person));
    }
    return result;
}

void DestroyPerson(Person *p) {
    if (p) {
        free(p->name);
        free(p);
    }
}

void SetPersonName(Person *p, const char *name) {
    if (p) {
        if (p->name) {
            free(p->name);
            p->name = NULL;
        }

        if (name) {
            size_t len = strlen(name);
            p->name = malloc(len + 1);
            if (p->name) {
                strncpy(p->name, name, len);
                p->name[len] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

const char *GetPersonName(const Person *p) {
    if (p)
        return p->name;
    return NULL;
}
```

However, as you can see by the amount of code involved, C++ is often the better choice:

```
class Person {
    private: std::string name;

    public: const std::string& getName(void) const {
        return this->name;
    }

    public: void setName(const std::string& newName) {
        this->name = newName;
    }
};
```

Much shorter, cleaner, and clearer!